# DC current stopper

Tags: dc, timer

I don't really know what I am looking to make is called so I am going to try to explain it.

I set up a motion activated light in my room. The lowest time interval is 60 seconds and I am okay with that. But I'd like to take the power from that to also turn on a small buzzer and a led light near my bed.

The problem is that I don't want it to last for 60 seconds but more like 5 seconds. I have electrical engineering background so I know all the basics. I just never had to do anything like this before.

Some extra info the light is AC I plan on using a 9v wall wart for conversion.

** Edit I have a Store bought motion sensing light like the flood lights for outside. I took of the included halogen Lights and hooked it up yo a small power strip so every time someone walks by my door it turns a desk lamp on. I also want to plug in a small wall wart to the the power strip but the only time interval  on the motion detector is is one minute 5 minutes and 10 mins but i only want the wall wart to power my buzzer and led for about 5 seconds thanks

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a "monostable multivibrator" or "single shot". http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/monostable.html

Comment: Are you trying to modify something you have bought or built or something else? Do you have circuit diagrams?

Comment: I bought motion sensing flood lights on sale for 5 dollars i removed the flood lights and re ran the cable to a desk lamp so i don't have the circuit diagram. Basically what i want to do is connect a wall wort to the sensor just like i did with the desk lamp but instead of being on for the full 60 seconds i want it to be on for only 5 seconds

Comment: Since the meaning of the question was clear enough for it to have been successfully answered - as evidenced by the upvotes - why is the question on hold?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, and if you want to play with the circuit, the LTspice circuit file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g2q77c1gtoshhqv/LED%20buzzer.asc).

[image]

Comment: I was going to recommend a 1-shot timer based on a 555 timer, but you beat me to it! (voted)